# Adding TreeViewItem fires twice, but not in single step

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I've got a serious problem here.
I have 4 TreeViews and when I am moving a TreeViewItem with DnD inside the TreeView everything is fine. When I move it from one TreeView to the other, the TreeViewItem is added twice.
And now comes the curious thing: Only when I run the app normally. If I run it in single step, to see what happens, everything works as expected and the Item is added only once. It is even enough to stop it on the first line of the OnDrop-Event and then let it run normally. Then it is only added once, instead of twice.
To put an "e.Handled = true" in the OnDrop-Event does NOT help.
Here is the XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="LibraryTreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
</Style>

<TreeView Name="MarketingScreenTreeView" Height="800"
          SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_OnSelectedItemChanged"
          PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="MarketingScreenTreeView_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
          PreviewMouseMove="TreeView_OnPreviewMouseMove"
          AllowDrop="True" PreviewDragOver="TreeView_OnPreviewDragOver"
          Drop="TreeView_OnDrop"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LibraryTreeViewItemStyle}" />
```

And here is the cs-Code:

```
private void TreeView_OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    _isDragging = false;
    _dragTimer.Stop();

    if (e.Source.GetType() == typeof(TreeView))
        return;

    TreeViewItem sourceItem = (TreeViewItem) e.Data.GetData("System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem");
    TreeViewItem sourceParentItem = (TreeViewItem) sourceItem.Parent;
    TreeView sourceTreeView = GetTreeView(sourceItem);
    TreeViewItem targetItem = (TreeViewItem) e.Source;
    TreeViewItem targetParentItem = GetParentTreeViewItem(targetItem);
    TreeView targetTreeView = GetTreeView(targetItem);
    if (ReferenceEquals(sourceParentItem, targetItem) || ReferenceEquals(sourceItem, targetItem) || 
        sourceTreeView.Name.Equals("MarketingScreenTreeView") && !targetTreeView.Name.Equals("MarketingScreenTreeView"))
        return;

    if (targetItem.Tag.Equals("sortObject"))
    {
        if (!sourceItem.Tag.Equals("screenObject") || !Equals(sourceTreeView, targetTreeView))
            return;
        sourceParentItem.Items.Remove(sourceItem);
        targetItem.Items.Add(sourceItem);
        sourceItem.IsSelected = true;
        return;
    }

    if (targetItem.Tag.Equals("screenObject"))
    {
        if (sourceItem.Tag.Equals("screenObject") && Equals(sourceTreeView, targetTreeView))
            MoveTreeViewItem(sourceParentItem, sourceItem, targetParentItem, targetItem, e);
        else if (!sourceItem.Tag.Equals("screenObject"))
        {
            if (Equals(sourceTreeView, targetTreeView))
            {
                sourceParentItem.Items.Remove(sourceItem);
                targetItem.Items.Add(sourceItem);
            }
            else if(targetTreeView.Name.Equals("MarketingScreenTreeView"))
            {
                TreeViewItem newItem = new TreeViewItem
                {
                    Header = sourceItem.Header,
                    Tag = sourceItem.Tag
                };
                newItem.Selected += TreeViewItemOnSelected;
                targetItem.Items.Add(newItem);
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    if (sourceItem.Tag.Equals("screenObject"))
        return;

    MoveTreeViewItem(sourceParentItem, sourceItem, targetParentItem, targetItem, e);
}

private static TreeView GetTreeView(FrameworkElement sourceItem)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (sourceItem.Parent.GetType() == typeof (TreeViewItem))
            sourceItem = (TreeViewItem) sourceItem.Parent;
        else
            return (TreeView) sourceItem.Parent;
    }
}

private void MoveTreeViewItem(TreeViewItem sourceParentItem, TreeViewItem sourceItem,
    TreeViewItem targetParentItem, TreeViewItem targetItem, DragEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem copyItem;
    TreeView sourceTreeView = GetTreeView(sourceItem);
    TreeView targetTreeView = GetTreeView(targetItem);

    if (Equals(sourceTreeView, targetTreeView))
    {
        sourceParentItem.Items.Remove(sourceItem);
        copyItem = sourceItem;
    }
    else
    {
        copyItem = new TreeViewItem
        {
            Header = sourceItem.Header,
            Tag = sourceItem.Tag
        };

        if(!copyItem.Tag.Equals("screenObject"))
            copyItem.Selected += TreeViewItemOnSelected;
    }

    List<TreeViewItem> allChildItems = targetParentItem.Items.Cast<TreeViewItem>().ToList();
    Point mousePoint = e.GetPosition(targetItem);
    int listPosition;

    if (mousePoint.Y < 8) //(targetItem.ActualHeight / 2))
        listPosition = targetParentItem.Items.IndexOf(targetItem);
    else
        listPosition = targetParentItem.Items.IndexOf(targetItem) + 1;

    targetParentItem.Items.Clear();
    bool itemFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <= allChildItems.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == listPosition)
        {
            targetParentItem.Items.Add(copyItem);
            itemFound = true;
        }
        else if (itemFound)
            targetParentItem.Items.Add(allChildItems[i - 1]);
        else
            targetParentItem.Items.Add(allChildItems[i]);
    }
}
```

Anyone any ideas of that could be?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, one solution seems to be to set a simple

```
if (!_isDragging)
    return;
```

But I wonder anyways why I get a different result in single step testing...